# MySQL query to display data from joined tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, one is for merits they recieved, and the other is for the list of possible merits, and every merit it part of a bigger catagory

#### table 1

```
merit_id
merit_name
merit_desc
cat_id
```

#### table 2

```
uid
merit_id
```

now what happens is in the php page, the user enter a catagory, and I want to display all the merits in said catagory and the one that the user already has, to display them first.

```
SELECT * FROM $achiev_table(table1) 
LEFT JOIN $user_achiev_table(table2) using(merit_ID) 
where $achiev_table.area_id=$area_id
ORDER BY UID DESC
```

the query I use for the php is as stated, and the problem is that it displays the merits more than once, and if I add a where clause to include the UID='$uid' than nothing is displayed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the merits from category X that user Y has:

```
SELECT m.merit_id, m.merit_name
FROM merits m
JOIN users_merits um ON m.merit_id = um.merit_id
WHERE m.cat_id = X
AND um.uid = Y
```

To get all the merits from category X:

```
SELECT m.merit_id, m.merit_name
FROM merits m
WHERE m.cat_id = X
```

EDITED: To get all the merits from category X, and show the ones user Y already has at the top (I am guessing that's what you meant):

```
SELECT m.merit_id, m.merit_name, um.uid as `user`
FROM merits m
LEFT JOIN users_merits um ON m.merit_id = um.merit_id AND um.uid = Y
WHERE m.cat_id = X
ORDER BY user, m.merit_name DESC
```

---

Explanation:

The `LEFT JOIN` attaches records from users_merits table to records from merits table, if there are records to attach.

That means, that for every record in *merits* that satisfies the `WHERE` clause, the DB will try to match a record (or records) from *users_merits* that satisfy the condition in the `ON` clause.

Being a `LEFT JOIN` (unlike a simple `JOIN`), all the records from the main table (*merits*) will be shown even if they have no matches in *users_merits* - as long as they satisfy the `WHERE` clause. Originally I put the `uid = Y` in the `WHERE` clause, so merits that were not received by user Y were not showing.

Finally we get a table of merits, all of them from category X, some of them achieved by user Y - those have a uid attached to them while others have `NULL`. `ORDER BY uid` puts the ones with the uid above the ones with `NULL`.

P.S. My SQL is better than my English, hope this is helpful :)

Comment: Well, I tried those queries, and basically I want than even if a user don't have any merits, all of them will be displayed. using the last query you provided, it only shows the merits if the user has them.

Comment: SELECT kaizen_achievments.aid, kaizen_achievments.achieve_name, kaizen_user_achievments.uid as `user`
FROM kaizen_achievments
LEFT JOIN kaizen_user_achievments ON kaizen_achievments.aid = kaizen_user_achievments.aid
WHERE kaizen_achievments.area_id = '29'
AND (kaizen_user_achievments.uid = '104' or isnull(uid))
ORDER BY user, kaizen_achievments.achieve_name DESC using this query it's getting there, but the problem is that it doesn't display the merits which users have already been rewarded for.

Comment: You're totally awesome guy, thanks, can you explain me the logic a bit so I won't be lost next time?

Answer (score 0):

You want to SELECT FROM the merit table, left join user table, where UID=$uid OR UID IS NULL, order by uid.